# Writing a job requirement for a web application developer

Tags: web-development, web-applications, hiring

I'm currently writing a job requirement for a software engineer position for my company, in which we are looking for a developer to work on client-side web application work. How should I title the job title / position? I don't necessarily want to call it a "Web Developer", for fear that it might attract more designer-y types. On the other hand, "Software Engineer" doesn't really give the indication that the work, while application based, will be web-based. Is "Web Application Software Engineer" a valid position title?

Also, I'm somewhat torn on what the required skills set should be. I don't necessarily think that the ideal candidate should have x years of experience in say, JavaScript or ActionScript, but rather am just looking for someone who has experience in developing client-side applications, and is willing to learn and develop web applications. My current attempt at this, is that I have a section in which I state:

> Experience in the following frameworks
>   and technologies are a plus, but not
>   necessarily required for the position:

Comment: Got to craigslist.com, scan the local jobs directory, read two dozen relevant ads, then think the places that you want to work for, and plagiarize like there is no tomorrow.

Comment: Super Awesome Senior Web Guy ;)

Answer (score 3):

I think stating what you are looking for in English is better than listing years of experience in specific technologies.  List the qualities of your ideal candidate and a description of what you would be expecting from them on a daily basis.  This would give potential candidates a much better idea of what the job will be like rather than guess based on the technologies involved.

As far as a title that might depend a little on where you are located.

Comment: Located in San Francisco, CA.

Answer (score 1):

Programmers, developers, coders, engineers it starts to get hairy. I think it would be clear enough if you just mention "code" or "coding skills" in the requirements or in the short description below the ad. Designers tend to avoid everything that has to do with it. Web Developer or just Coder or Programmer would fit as a title. Someone who can code native applications for example and is willing to learn I don't think the transition would take that much. Mentioning some of the technologies you are using internally would certainly attract more appropriate candidates.

Answer (score 1):

Web Application Software Engineer might be fine, as long as there are no legal restrictions on the use of the word engineer where you are located. Web Application Developer might work also.

For the frameworks and technologies, you might be able to state it in terms of what the person will be working with, e.g., "Ability to program web applications using the following frameworks..."

Answer (score 1):

Web Programmer is a simple way of putting it. It also happens to be the job I'm in and your description of the job sounds like what I'm doing. I think it conveys the importance of implementing logic in the role.

I think that the title is more important than the description, but it depends on where you're posting the job listing. If a non-web-based programmer sees a 'web developer' position, they might ignore it.

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for a developer to work on client-side web application work, advertise for a client-side web application developer.

Calling it something else is an endemic problem in the industry that I would try to avoid.  Call a spade a spade.